File Permissions on Qbittorrent - "Errored: Couldn't write to file"
I'm having an issue with qbittorrent.
As a new user to linux, im still wrapping my head around it, but slowly getting there.
I'm trying to download files to my NAS mounted via NFS to /mnt/NAS/torrents/ where the download would complete and the 'arr's (radarr,sonarr etc) will then transfer the files to /mnt/NAS/Shows or /Movies.
However, when the download starts, qbittorrent freaks out and says "Errored: Couldn't write to file".
This was strange as I changed all the permissions to user and still no good.
I thought then, get qbittorrent to download to /data/torrents/ but i still get the same error.
The only time it DOES work is when qbittorrent downloads to its defult folder /home/swayze/Downloads/Torrents.
All the permissins are set to root or swayze(me) and Qbittorrent is also running as Swaze(me).
Why is it im getting this error from qbittorrent when it has all the permissions it needs?
Any advice!
thanks all

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.
